# Routing unexisting folders to PHP script with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to route all unexisting folders to a specific PHP script with mod_rewrite but I couldn't handle it.

Here is the scenario, I've some folders like /images, /gallery, /js etc. Some of them has their own .htaccess files and php scripts under directories...

What I have to do is, without blocking these folders and their own rules redirecting all other requests to /subject/content.php file..

I tried something like this but unfortunately doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)-(.*).html /subject/content.php?ID=$2
```

At the end, URLs should be like /sports/123-how-to-lose-weight.html

Also I'm trying the same for category pages. And they should be routed like
www.blabla.com/sports  -->  /subject/category.php?cat=sports

(ps: I also couldn't see anything on RewriteLog with level 9 logging when requesting pages according to upper rules)

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try these;

```
// stop greedy search by "?" while using .*
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*?)-(.*?)\.html /subject/content.php?ID=$2
// or more better regexp, afak \w & \d will wolk too
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]+)/(\d+)-([\w\d-]+)\.html /subject/content.php?ID=$2
// if not set as RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]+)/(\d+)-([\w\d-]+)\.html subject/content.php?ID=$2
```

But first: `RewriteEngine On`. :)

Comment: In fact, /sports is not important in the URL, I only use "123" part which is the document ID in PHP script. So I guess it should be $2

Comment: I guess the rule doesn't work anyway because I can't see its trying to reach content.php on RewriteLog with level 9 logging.

Comment: oooops... you wouldn't believe but I realized that I forgot 'RewriteEngine On' on .htaccess file. Thank you very much for your help, it seems it's working now :)